# Camera takes long to capture images in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I am working on an app which includes camera feature,at a time user can capture upto 5 images one after another.I am using avfoundation for capturing multiple images all thing is working properly but only issue is when i am clicking on capture button,it takes around 5 seconds to capture ,Can anybudy please help me wheer i am wrong?my code is as below.

**code**

```
        AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
         [session beginConfiguration];
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
-(void)takePhoto :(UIViewController *)sender
{

    if ([CustomCamera isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {

        currentPicker = self.picker;
        self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        if (self.mediatype == VIDEOTYPE)
        {

            self.picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
            self.picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;
            self.picker.videoMaximumDuration = 180.0f;
        }
        else{

                //self.multipleImagePicker = [[RPMultipleImagePickerViewController alloc] init];
                self.multipleImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                self.multipleImagePicker.delegateCaptureImage = self;
                self.picker.delegate = self;
                self.picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
                self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
                self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
                self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
                [self setCameraOverlayView];

            //Added by jigar...
                camOverLayView.view.alpha = 0.0f;
                self.picker.cameraOverlayView = camOverLayView.view;
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDelay:2.2f];
                camOverLayView.view.alpha = 1.0f;
                [UIView commitAnimations];

            //setting delay to capture screen

        }
        [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"No Camera Available in Device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }


}
```

Comment: Is CustomCamera anything special, as in third party? Which device are you testing this on?

Comment: Try dropping anything that's not essential to the process, like your animations etc., and put an NSLog in your take photo method and the returned delegate method: how long does it take in your log?

Comment: @SunburstEnzo -yes i have used Avfoundation for camera function

Comment: @JohnnyRockex-i have noticed that when i am changing the presets for the camera capture the time is relatively changing but my issue is it takes more time when preset is of high resolution and when i am going for low preset it is quick but the resolution is very poor and blurry.